# Can React Hooks have methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, react-hooks

How does one write a React Hooks function to export methods in the `export default`?

I don't see examples anywhere, so I suspect that React Hooks don't work this way, but... I'm curious if it is possible to extend the hook function to export child methods.

---

*Checkout.js:*

```
import React from "react";

function Checkout() {
  return <section className="checkout"></section>;
}

// Add Item Method
Checkout.addItemPrice = (item, price) => {
  console.log("this is a method");
};

export default Checkout;
```

*Checkout.test.js:*

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";

describe("Checkout Test Suite", () => {
    it("Can add an item", () => {
        var checkout = new Checkout();
        checkout.addItemPrice('a', 1);
    });
});
```

---

**TypeError: checkout.addItemPrice is not a function**

I haven't been able to find a way to write this in Hooks, but at the end of the day, I wind up splitting them into 2 functions, with 2 exports, and 2 imports.

Comment: Overall, I'd say you're thinking about it the wrong way.  Functions don't have methods.  Just write other functions and you're done!

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350). Attaching a method to a React element is usually an antipattern and indicates, as @jmargolisvt writes, that you're likely approaching the problem the wrong way. Why do you need a method? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Honestly, the problem I am trying to solve is to stitch together a Nodejs TDD tutorial that I am doing, and trying to apply it to React. And then, curiosity got me wondering how, if at all, this would be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with hooks. If you want your `new Checkout()` instance to have a `addItemPrice` method, then you should add it to the prototype:

```
Checkout.prototype.addItemPrice = (item, price) => {
```

Comment: This, sadly, doesn't work either. I had tried passing it to the prototype in my earlier troubleshooting, and unfortunately, same error.

Comment: Do you have something we can run to replicate your issue?

Comment: You must move this prototype definition into checkout.test.js module.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute:

`var checkout = new Checkout();`

an object of type `reactComponent` is returned to a `checkout` variable regardless of `New` keyword is used or not. 
This object doesn't have a method you are trying to call.
You may try to define your method using a `prorotype` chain of this object (of reactComponent), but this object may be protected against any changes.

Even if you manage to set a method to `reactComponet`, this is not a good thing and surely not a React way to do things.